# Calculate a voltage angle offset for a 3-Phase utility meter

Tags: three-phase, power-meter

I'm trying to analyze and write a program around some data that I was given. The data is a collection of readings from 3 Phase smart meters of an electrical utility. One value in the data that I can not for the life of me understand is something called a "Voltage Angle Offset" or VAO. Here is what a few records of data look like for each of the phases:

```
Volts          Amps             Angle       Power Factor    VAO
124,121,220    23.3,45.3,20.4   0,180,270   353,356,270     7,4,90
122,122,213    9.3,8.9,9.1      0,180,270   44,280,15       44,80,15
121,121,210    27,21.9,13.1     0,180,270   18,25,273       18,25,87
122,122,212    7.9,7.7,9.7      0,180,270   52,299,310      52,61,50
124,125,216    13.1,11.6,12.9   0,180,270   303,246,270     57,114,90
123,123,214    9.4,11,13.9      0,180,270   126,34,86       126,34,86
122,122,212    12.7,21.8,24.2   0,180,270   23,298,356      23,62,4
122,121,206    36.8,50.7,38     0,180,270   125,36,46       125,36,46
```

I can't figure out how one would calculate the VAO given the other bits of information. I'm not an electrical engineer by any meaning of the word (a computer programmer, actually), so perhaps I'm interpreting the data completely wrong.

Any insight?

Comment: I've never heard the term, but it certainly looks like just the complement of the Power Factor.  353+7=360, 356+4=360, 270+90=360.

Comment: Took a look at your comment and thought you might have it right. However, Looking at some other records of data, the complement doesn't seem to be a pattern. Take a look at the extra data I added.

Comment: Honestly, it looks like that data is messed up.  Where the correlation doesn't exist, the values are duplicated for PF and VAO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VAO is the angle by which the power factor (expressed as an angle) is away from zero degrees relative to its phase regardless of whether it is leading or lagging.

ie 0 degrees and 360 degrees are the same angle = resistive.

VAO is either

- PF if PF is < 180
  so PF - VAO = 0
- 360 - PF if PF > 180
  so PF + VAO = 360

Clear as mud! :-) - don't worry  - it's one of those Doh! things. Stare at what I've written, look at the figures and tables and suddenly it will go 'boing' and be completely obvious.
Impossible to "unsee" once seen - like eg [Old hag turns into beautiful girl illusion](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=old+hag+beautiful+girl&espv=2&biw=1396&bih=877&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=QeeCVcbcHqTdmAXQlIC4Aw&ved=0CCMQsAQ#tbm=isch&q=old+hag+beautiful+girl+optical+illusion), or theatre curtains fold other way or ...)

[image]

Comment: What you're suggesting seems to be consistent with all of my data, and I think you've explained it well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd be concerned if the voltage jumped around like it does in the example (121 volts to 220 volts is a lot). Also the "Angles" seem all wrong - I'd have thought they would be 0, 120, 240 to match the 3 phase angles of the supply (assuming a balanced load).

Power factor should be no-more than unity so figures of 353,356,270 are meaningless as this question stands.

My advice is go back to the person giving you the information and ask whay each number means precisely.

Comment: It is hard to see from the data provided, but it looks like a single phase residential system (US/North America), with 240VAC phase to phase, and 120VAC phase to neutral.  The 270 Degree reading for angle seems odd though.  Power Factor is normally represented at 0 to 1, but it can equally be represented by the actual phase angle in degrees.